# Original object getting modified, even though I'm using the spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React app where you have a have a form where you can add a new employee and X number of dependents.

In the form, I set a default state like this:

```
class NewEmployee extends Component {
  state = {
    employees: [],
    costEstimates: { ...emptyCosts },
    relationshipOptions: [],
    newEmployee: { ...emptyEmployee }
  };
```

That `emptyEmployee` is coming from a const in a separate file, and it looks like this:

```
export const emptyEmployee = { firstName: '', lastName: '', dependents: [] };
```

I do this purely to just try and keep the initial state looking tidy in the code.

My problem is that the `dependents` array in `emptyEmployee` is getting modified, and I don't understand how. This is the function getting called when the user clicks to add a new dependent:

```
  handleNewDependent = () => {
    const newEmployee = { ...this.state.newEmployee };
    // blank dependent for now
    const dependent = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };

    newEmployee.dependents.push(dependent);

    this.setState({ newEmployee });
  };
```

I've pinpointed that this is when the `dependents` array of my `emptyEmployee` object gets modified. I don't understand how, since I use the spread operator to make a copy.

Comment: Spread only results in a shallow copy.

Comment: The question got closed. So here I am writing it for you. You can do like `newEmployee: { ...emptyEmployee, dependents: emptyEmployee.dependents.slice() }`.. Now `dependents` is pointing a cloned Array.